# Coping with a label/class imbalance in DESeq2

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do differential expression on label imbalanced data; my case:control ratio is 2:1.

I know that regressions are at the core of DESeq2 machinery and I know regressions have internal machinery for coping with such imbalances.

Specifically, you can down-weight observations from the over-represented group to force an equal contribution to the learning. Is observation weighting available to the user in DESeq2?

Group `a` over-represented in learning:

```
glm( gene_i ~ effect , data[,c('a','a','a','a','b','b')] )
```

Group `a` and `b` equal representation in learning:

```
glm( gene_i ~ effect , data[,c('a','a','a','a','b','b')] , weight=c(.5,.5,.5,.5,1,1) )
```

Comment: I've had very good success getting immediate feedback from Michael Love (author of DESeq2) posting on https://support.bioconductor.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that too. I also posted on Biostars.

Comment: being answered at: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/87507/#87518